# How to Find Specific Network Computer Information

Tags: vb.net

I did lookup on StackOverflow and Googled, but did not find any code that can help me on this.
Request help here on this please.

We have a network with many computers. I would want to enter the name of a computer and should be able to get back the OSArchitecture, IPAddress and Full Computer Name.

I want to achieve this using VB.net
I tried using the "My.Computer.Name" and related options, but it gives me details of my computer only, I would to query the details of a specific computer on the network.

Note: This is a domain controlled network, not requesting for Home Workgroup

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Am sorry, I totally forgot about the title part.
Will keep in mind. Any help on this please.

Comment: Consider using WMI. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404655.aspx) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the IP addresses is straight forward:

```
Dim ips As IPAddress[] 
ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())
```

The other information you could get through [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257337%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: `Public Class Form1
 Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim message As String
  If proctype = 1 Then
   message = "64 Bit"
  Else
   message = "32 Bit"
  End If
   MsgBox("Process Type is: " + message)
 End Sub

 Private proctype As Integer
 Property Is64BitProcess As Boolean
  Get
   Return proctype
  End Get
  Set(ByVal Value As Boolean)
  proctype = Value
  End Set
 End Property
End Class`

I tried this, but am not sure where to pass the network computer hostname in this so that it will return the value,please help